# On the complexity of Bandwidth Minimization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

The graph bandwidth problem is defined as follows. Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, a *layout* $f$ of $G$ is a one-to-one mapping of the vertices of $G$ onto the integers $\{1, \ldots, |V|\}$. The *bandwidth of $f$* is defined as

$bw(f) = \max \{|f(u) - f(v)| \mid \{u,v\} \in E\}$.

The *bandwidth of $G$*, denoted $bw(G)$, is defined as the minimum bandwidth of a layout, the minimum being taken over all possible layouts.

The decision question is: given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, is $bw(G) \le k$?

This problem is known to be NP-complete even for trees of maximum degree three [*[Complexity Results for Bandwidth Minimization](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2100947).* Garey, Graham, Johnson and Knuth, SIAM J. Appl. Math., Vol. 34, No.3, 1978]. The authors show that one can test whether a graph has bandwidth at most two in polynomial time. The case $bw \le 3$ was open.

Is the complexity of the case $bw \le 3$ known? What do we know about the complexity of the problem when $k$ is not part of the input but a fixed constant at least $4$?

References would be nice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bandwidth problem is $W[t]$-hard for all $t$. It was shown by Bodlaender et al. in "Beyond NP-completeness for problems of bounded width." See [the paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/195058.195229).

On the other hand, it is also known that for any $k$, whether a given graph has bandwidth at most $k$ can be decided in $O(f(k)n^{k+1})$ time. This implies that the bandwidth problem is in $XP$. See the [another paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0601042) by Saxe.

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer my question. The problem may be polynomial-time decidable for the case $bw \le 3$ and still be hard for every level of the $W$-hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, my answer was not so complete. It is also known that for any $k$, whether a given graph has bandwidth at most $k$ can be decided in $O(f(k) n^{k+1})$ time for any $k$. This implies that the bandwidth problem is in $XP$. See the another paper by Saxe ( http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0601042 ). Does this answer the remaining part of your question?

Comment: I think that the paper by Saxe answers the question completely.  Can you edit the answer to include it?

Comment: The answer has been edited. Thanks Tsuyoshi.

Comment: Yes, it does answer my question. Thanks much.

Comment: by clicking the check-mark on the left of my answer :-)